# Value of optional type String? not unwrapped

Tags: ios, swift

I am just not able to unwrap `else` block. xCode gives me options to "Fix it with ! and ??", which sadly does not fix the issue either.
I get this error in xCode:
Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use ! or ??

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(theButton: UIButton) {
    if answerField.text == "0" {
        answerField.text = theButton.titleLabel?.text
    } else {
        answerField.text  = answerField.text + theButton.titleLabel?.text
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because theButton.titleLabel?.text it not unwrapped.

You can use

```
 answerField.text  = answerField.text + (theButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "")
```

or

```
if answerField.text == "0" {
    answerField.text = theButton.titleLabel?.text
} else {
    if let txt = theButton.titleLabel?.text {
        answerField.text  = answerField.text + txt
    } else {
        answerField.text  = answerField.text
    }
}
```

Comment: I know  we are not allowed (kinda) to say Thank You, but THANK YOU ZuYuan! Worked like a charm!!! :)