# Compile error with optional binding

Tags: swift

With Xcode 7 beta 5, The following code:

```
public func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    guard let title: String = annotation.title else // compile error
    {
        return nil
    }

    ...
```

...does not compile with error "*Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?*".
**MKAnnotation** is a protocol with **optional String**:

```
public protocol MKAnnotation : NSObjectProtocol {

    ...
    optional public var title: String? { get }
    ...
}
```

It may be obvious but I can't see what is wrong. Do you see?
Thanks.

EDIT: I dont believe it is a duplicate of "[Value of optional type String? not unwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799529/value-of-optional-type-string-not-unwrapped)" as there is not tentative of optional binding in the later case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value of optional type String? not unwrapped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799529/value-of-optional-type-string-not-unwrapped)

Comment: Strange. Can you use optional binding instead of a guard statement and get it to work?

Comment: I used optional binding with "if let" before using guard, same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the answer: "optional" and "?" seem to make the type to be bound equivalent to a double optional String, that is: "String??". The following code does compile fine:

```
    guard let titleStillOptional = annotation.title, let title = titleStillOptional else
    {
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't set the type in guard, just use:

```
guard let title = annotation.title else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: My initial code was without the type but then the title type is inferred as a String? and forced me to put title! everywhere.

Comment: It seems to work but it only binds the first optional, not the second one. If you want to use your title in the code as a String, you need to force unwrap with !. Do you agree?

Comment: Yeah, looked into it and it seems like it. If you unwrap `annotation.title` it `returns` optional which you then need to unwrap again. `annotation.title` is of type `String??`, seems a bit off to me.